# Making my printed output appear on the same line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
number=int(input("Input a positive number less than 100:"))
perfect=1
for perfect in range (1,number):
    a=perfect*perfect
    if a >= number:
        break
    print (a)
```

It will output:

```
Input a positive number less than 100:81
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
```

but It will do these all on a separate line

#### How do I make it so they all print on the same line?

Comment: Thanks a lot idjaw :)!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `end` argument in the `print` function:

```
print(..., end=" ")
```

Answer (score 0):

#### [This is what you are looking for](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#print):

```
print(a, end=" ") # Appends a space instead of a newline
```